# Update a Generic List

Tags: c#

The list contains multiple values and I am trying to figure out how to update the selected item which will come in from the object Parameter. Can someone show me how to do this.

--Update Method--

```
public void updateSelectedItemGrid(object Parameter)
{
    if (Parameter != null)
    {
        string test1 = ((Test.SharedLib.Data.testSubBO)(Parameter)).Term;
        Int64 test2 = Convert.ToInt64(((testSubBO)(Parameter)).ComputerId);

        ComputerDataGridListTest.Add(new ComputerDataGridBO()
        {
           //Not sure what to do here??
            Term = test1,
            ComputerId = test2
        });
    }
}
```

--ComputerDataGridBO--

```
class ComputerDataGridBO
{
    public Int64 ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }

}
```

--List--

```
public List<ComputerDataGridBO> ComputerDataGridListTest { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are just adding another entry to the List instead of updating an existing entry.

Try this

```
public void updateSelectedItemGrid(object Parameter)
{
    if (Parameter == null) return;

    var parameter = Parameter as Test.SharedLib.Data.testSubBO;

    if (parameter == null) return;

    var computerid = Convert.ToInt64(parameter.ComputerId);

    var item = ComputerDataGridListTest.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ComputerId == computerid);

    if(item != null)
        item.Term = paramter.Term;

}
```

It's probably a lot easier if you change your signature to accept the right object!

```
public void updateSelectedItemGrid(Test.SharedLib.Data.testSubBO parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null) return;

    var item = ComputerDataGridListTest.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ComputerId == parameter.computerid);

    if(item != null)
        item.Term = paramter.Term;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for the something like that

```
var existsItems = ComputerDataGridListTest.Where(x => x.ComputerId == test2);
if(existsItems.Any())
    foreach(var item in existsItems)
        item.Term = test2;
else
    ComputerDataGridListTest.Add(new ComputerDataGridBO()
    {
        Term = test1,
        ComputerId = test2
    });
```

Don't forget to use System.Linq.